# angularjs and server side authorization

Tags: java, angularjs, security, authorization

i'm new to Angular js and SPA and I'm facing with the matter of authorization on editing\viewing data and pages.

My specific case is about a quite complex page which can have:

- some data in the page editable only when the managed object is in a certain state and by users having a specific role, but viewable by other roles, including some action buttons.
- pages or part of pages viewable only by certain roles at a certain state of the managed object.

I'm used to server side web applications written in java and normally i do data authorization processing (editable\not editable) at server level and it's quite easy.

With Angular js, from what I've seen till now, all that should be handled at client level, so putting in JS the logic which decides whether an input and\or  a page can be seen or not, and so on.
This could potentially be modified by a 'smart' user using the Development Tools of the browser (modifying pages, DOM, CSS JS and more).
I know that in any case the final authorization is performed by the server when the remote rest service is called (saving data, reading data), but I would like that the user don't even have ANY possibility of viewing the existence of sensitive data\pages.
I.E i would like is something like that:

- editable\not editable\viewable\not viewable data --> the server provides the AngularJS template with correct tags in it, Angular provides page logic, call to the REST WS, data binding, event handling etc
- viewable\not viewable pages -> the server provides the template or and 'unauthorized' page, Angularjs does the rest of work

Some techniques I've seen partially can avoid some situations, but they are anyway not completely the best for me.

- Hiding "forbidden" data --> on server side we can avoid to send authorized JSON data. OK, but the user can always see the 'existence' of such data with DEv Tools. Anyway this is not such a big issue.
- Authorizing data editing --> no other solution found than let it handle by Angular js.
- Authorizing pages with roles -simple : Forbidden pages are handled by Angular which makes them visible if the user role is in the list of page's authorized roles.
  User role is sent at login time and bootstrap checks if OK or not when the page\view is requested. Easily changeable by the smart user.
- Authorizing pages with roles -advanced
  the server, at bootstrap time, send the list of roles authorized for a page or action on the data (create, update delete etc), Angular checks that the user role is in the list of authorized roles when the page is requested. Better than the previous, but the smart user can anyway know about roles authorization and with Development Tools can unlock forbidden pages (if he's smart enough).
- Authorizing pages with function authorization: similar, but better, than previous solutions. The server sends the authorization required for the page and, at login time, sends the list of authorizations for the user. This makes more difficult to the smart user handling authorization logic and take completely away from the smart user the knowledge of application roles  and their authorizations (GOOD). But at the end he could unlock these pages anyway.

All this could be easily solved (for example in java) with some filters or interceptors for the page auths (eventually with libs such as Spring Security), and with some simple EL at template level, which removes data that the user could not see, removes forbidden inputs and serves the page to angular, but as I read, even this basic server processing seems to be discouraged.

Any solution ?
Why I can't do that ?

Best Greetings,
Massimo

Comment: You can definitely use server side security to stop templates from being loaded if a particular user doesn't have the correct roles/privileges.  In 99/100 cases protecting the template doesn't actually make a difference it's the data you care about protecting.  If you are concerned with protecting the templates then by all means do so with server side security, nothing you do in the client is safe from prying eyes.  Aside from that anyone can write or use any number of existing programs to send modified garbage at your server so the client security is basically moot.